# Scrapy for login

Tags: python, login, web-crawler, scrapy

Eu peguei esse código da internet e mudei um pouco, para fazer login no site da cpfl, mas quando eu uso o comando `scrapt crawl myproject` nada acontece e o comando `scrapy runspider items.py` da o erro erro:

> No  element find in  <200
>   https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapp/>

SAbem me falar o que está errado?

```
import scrapy
BASE_URL = 'https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapp/#/login'
USER_NAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'
class ShareSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sharespider"
    start_urls = ['https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapp/#/login']
    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath='//form[@id="panelMobile"]',
            formdata={
                'documentoEmail': USER_NAME,             
                'Password': PASSWORD,             
                'Action':'1',
            },
            callback=self.after_login)
    def after_login(self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o formulário de entrada de usuário e senha não está na página que você está carregando - a página que você está carregando só tem código javascript, e o formulário é montado por esse código dinâmicamente.

Como o `scrapy` não executa javascript, não é possível usá-lo dessa forma neste site - isso te deixa com duas alternativas:

- Analisar o código javascript da página, descobrir o que ele faz, e "simular" isso com código python escrito manualmente. Essa solução geralmente é mais eficiente porém bem mais complexa de implementar.

  No caso específico do site da CPFL, parece que ao enviar o login, ele faz via javascript AJAX um `HTTP POST` em `https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapi/api/token` com os seguintes parâmetros:

  ```
  {
      'client_id': 'agencia-virtual-cpfl-web',
      'grant_type': 'password',
      'username', USER_NAME,
      'password': PASSWORD,
  }
  ```

  Para descobrir isso usei o modo inspector do Firefox (pressione `F12`) e tentei fazer o login, depois na aba `network` você consegue ver tudo que a página está fazendo na rede.

  ```
  yield scrapy.FormRequest(
      url='https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapi/api/token',
      formdata={
          'client_id': 'agencia-virtual-cpfl-web',
          'grant_type': 'password',
          'username', USER_NAME,
          'password': PASSWORD,
      },
      callback=self.after_login,
  )
  ```

  Esse código acima deve provavelmente te logar, mas o retorno não será uma página e sim algo como `'OK'` - você vai ter que continuar inspecionando a página com o navegador, para descobrir o que fazer com isso para obter o que você quer - logar é só o começo do problema.
- A outra alternativa bem mais simples de implementar é usar o `selenium` - é uma lib que permite controlar um navegador através do python, como o chrome ou o firefox - Usando ele é possível executar javascript. Porém é bem menos eficiente porque você está executando um browser inteiro...

Espero ter te colocado na direção correta.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, muito útil, então eu quero pegar as faturas e armazenar em uma pasta no meu pc, logando desse método que você me passou acredito que não de certo, mas ja deu uma ótima clareada para mim, muito obrigado, vou ver se consigo fazer pelo scrapy ainda, provavel que eu não consiga pois sou inciante nele ainda, mas ai vejo pelo selenium, valeu